# Making notifications easier to hear when listening to music

Tags: notifications, audio, music-player, volume-control

I would like to find some way to make it more likely for me to hear my notifications (mostly incoming SMS) while I'm playing music on my phone.

The phone does vibrate, but that is of little help if I'm not very close to it. And it does play the notification sound, but it easily gets lost among the music. It's very frustrating to miss a text message and answer it way too late even though you were right next to your phone.

Ideally, I'd want to make it so that the music's volume is cut for about a second of silence, then the notification sound would play, followed by another second of silence, and then the music would come back.

Actually that's the only solution I can think of, but I don't know everything. Surely, it's possible, since most media apps are able to cut their volume to play the ringtone if a call comes during playback. But does there exist a solution?

### Details

Google Nexus 4
Android 4.3

**Music applications in cause**
*(though I wish this not to be necessary, since a cross-application solution is required to be practical with several applications)*

- AlarmDroid (Internet radio stream)
- TuneIn Radio
- Rocket Player